# Getting a list item within a dictionary by key

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6, libraries

I have a list of state names:

```
stateNames = ['Alabama', 'Georgia', 'Florida']
```

And I have a dictionary that has a list of codes for each state name. *Not all states have codes. And I don't need the codes for all states, just the ones from the list:

```
masterdict = {'Alaska': [1,2,3], 'Alabama': [4, 5, 6], 'Arkansas': [7,8,9], 'Arizona': [], 'California': [], 'Colorado': [], 'Connecticut': [], 'DistrictOfColumbia': [], 'Delaware': [], 'Florida': [21, 48], 'Georgia': ['1,3,2,4,5'], 'Wyoming': []}
```

I want to look through my list and get the codes individually for each state in that list. I'm still a little off on the logic. One is a list(item in list) and one is a dictionary with keys ('state name') and values (list of codes). What am I doing incorrectly here:

```
for item in stateNames:
  for k in masterdict.item():  
      if item == masterdict[k]:
          print(masterdict[v])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first loop, you are getting all of the keys. So you don't need to do another loop. Just grab the value by the key.

```
for item in stateNames:
      print(masterdict[item])
```

Comment: Lol, I can't believe it was that simple! I think I need to review dictionary and list comprehension.Thanks.